Is this possible to add/update ribbon dynamically while runtime in word add-in created with officejs?
I am developing a Word add-in using OfficeJS and Angular. There is a requirement to update the ribbon text dynamically at runtime. Is this possible now?
I want to display the name of the current session, which I will update at runtime. I would like to show this text in the ribbon.

OfficeJS can define commands that appear in the Ribbon, including defining entire new Ribbon tabs - though given that ribbon commands have to be baked into an XML representation (a manifest) I don't think you'll be able to dynamic updates of custom commands.

I'm afraid that this cannot be done. The strings that appear on custom ribbon controls and groups are hardcoded in the add-in's manifest and cannot be changed at runtime. (As far as I can recall, this is even true of built-in ribbon controls. Although some ribbon tabs can appear in certain contexts, text on the ribbon does not change dynamically.)

I do not know enough js to give any answer. However it is possible, with XML and vba to create Ribbon menus that are dynamic. See https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/dynamic_ribbon_menu.html.
